# Py2neo - get node by id throws error when executed?

Tags: neo4j, py2neo

I was using python neo4j rest client in a project and just switched to Py2neo.

I tried to get a node from the database by its ID but got the following error :

```
AttributeError: 'GraphDatabaseService' object has no attribute 'get_node'
```

I used `get_node` function (http://nigelsmall.com/_api/py2neo/neo4j.html#py2neo.neo4j.GraphDatabaseService.get_node)

Am I doing something wrong or the doc should be updated ?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The link I was referring to wasn't updated according to Nigel Small

For py2neo > v1.5, we can get a node by Id as follows : `my_node = graph_db.node(id)`

Comment: And where did you get that id? How can I know the id of a node?